# How I reverse a Short in Scala?

Tags: scala, binary

```
 def reverse(w: Short): Short = { w.toBinaryString.reverse.toShort  }
```

This should be work like this:

```
reverse(0x0000.toShort)   
0x0000.toShort



reverse(0xFFFF.toShort)

0xFFFF.toShort



reverse(0xAAAA.toShort)  

0x5555.toShort 

reverse(0x1234.toShort)

0x2C48.toShort
```

Comment: Why do you want it to do in binary? What’s wrong with w.toString.reverse.toShort? And then you can convert it into binary.

Comment: @RamanMishra Your suggestion does not give the correct answers; try it on the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgo the `String` translations for a more mathematical approach.

```
def reverse(w :Short) :Short =
  Stream.iterate(w.toInt, 16)(_ >> 1)
        .foldLeft(0:Short){case (s,i) => ((s<<1)+(i&1)).toShort}
```

testing:

```
reverse(0) == 0                    //res0: Boolean = true
reverse(-1) == -1                  //res1: Boolean = true
reverse(0xAAAA.toShort) == 0x5555  //res2: Boolean = true
reverse(0x1234.toShort) == 0x2C48  //res3: Boolean = true
```